# Honda EU3000is K1 Generator - Replace Gas Tank

Tags: honda, fuel-tank, generator

I need to replace the fuel tank on a 3 year old Honda EU3000is K1 Generator.  Unfortunately gas was left in the fuel tank and the tank is now rusted.  I was able to get the generator working again but believe that replacing the fuel tank will be necessary to avoid future blockage issues in the carburetor. My problem is that in order to remove the fuel tank, the main cover surround must be removed.  Although the side panel of the main cover appears movable, the top of the main cover (particularly around the fuel filler and fuel filler neck seal) seems immovable.  I'm not certain the process for removal and would appreciate any advice to take of the main cover and access the fuel tank below.

Thanks in advance.
Bill

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't offer any specific advice on removing the tank, but I would like to offer the suggestion that you install an inline fuel filter between the tank and carburetor because doing so would prevent any particulates from entering the carburetor. It's an good idea if you end up replacing the tank or not, and would let you run it safely in the meantime. If it already has one then you can run it without worry of the carburetor getting damaged.

Comment: Thank you atraudes.  Excellent suggestion.  I will be certain to do just that.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

**[Here's the owners manual from the Honda Power Equipment website](http://cdn.powerequipment.honda.com/pe/pdf/manuals/00X31ZT76221.pdf)**

**It doesn't have what your looking for**

But, if you look on page 51 it shows how to remove fascia related to the front cover.  You will notice you are looking at the side of the gas tank beneath the top cover.

***a bunch of assumption***

I could be wrong.

I do have a lot of experience with the 80's era of Honda generator and this is obviously newer.

It may still be the way or similar to what I describe.

After you have removed the front fascia there are some fasteners where the top cover is attached to the fuel storage and the far edge is 'flat hook' as we used to call them where a piece of the top cover extends and fits into a slot and uses the bend as one side the mount and M5 or M6 bolts on the other side, mounting to the fuel cell.

I believe, using the pdf as the reference, you can just go in on that side and access the fuel tank so you can clean it with some acid or other good stuff.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you DucatiKiller.  Was able to remove the cover and access the tank.  Will be cleaning the tank.  Appreciate your help and the pdf of the owner's manual.  Bill

Comment: Can you hook me up with an upvote?   :-)

Answer (score -1):

I agree with atraudes. But would add a couple of things. 
Put the biggest filter with the finest filter Media you can get in there.
ALWAYS add a fuel stabilizer to your small engine fuel. NOT JUST When storing the equipment!!
In my experience (30years Professional lawn and garden equipment repair!) Honda parts prices rival the National debt!!
I pray you don"t have to replace the tank.